# php mysql export should create dropdown

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I'm trying to make a .xls export from a part of my mysql database. I came up with the following sollution:

//Get the data from database and write it to a table

```
$siteNumber = 999;
$results = Db::getInstance()->queryResults('SELECT * FROM `configurations`');
?>

<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Configuration id</th>
        <th>Configuration category</th>
        <th>Configuration name</th>
    </tr>

    <?php 
        foreach($results as $result => $key) {
            $str = '<tr>'; 
            $str .= '<td>'.$key->configuration_id .'</td>';
            $str .= '<td>'.$key->configuration_category .'</td>';
            $str .= '<td>'.$key->configuration_name .'</td>';
            $str .= '</tr>'; 
            echo $str;
        }

    ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

//And I use header to create a excelfile

```
<?php

// Add data table
include 'exceldata.php';

// The function header by sending raw excel
header("Content-type: application/vnd-ms-excel");

// Defines the name of the export file "codelution-export.xls"
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.xls");
?>
```

This all works fine and outputs a nice table. What I'm trying to achieve is all results get exported classified by configuration_category as dropdown.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: SELECT * FROM `configurations` ORDER BY someColumn (ASC or DESC)

Comment: Thats not really what I need. What I would like to do is having dropdowns within the excelsheet ordered by configuration category. So category 1 is one dropdown with results, 2 is one dropdown with results etc.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do.  Could you make some attempt and include it in your question so that we have a better idea of what you want?

Comment: Allright, let me put it different. What I would like to do is to get all the $results that get exported to the excelfile as a dropdown in excel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure i understand. ButIf you want to exprt the exelfile with included dropdown you can just make use of html with unordered list

Answer (score 0):

I guess this: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel is what you need.

PHPExcel will allow you to create beautiful spreadsheets and export them into Excel format.

You can create Excel DropDowns using this library as well. See this page for details: [Read the list of options in a drop-down list - Phpexcel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18377976/read-the-list-of-options-in-a-drop-down-list-phpexcel)

Comment: This is not really an answer but an alternative. Not really what i'm looking for but thanks.